# pylint "invalid syntax" (syntax-error) from '*='

Tags: python, while-loop, pylint

I'm getting a syntax error from pylint, and I believe the error is occurring from using a `*=`. My original code only used a `*` but that gave me the wrong answers on questions. I've tried multiple variations on `*=` but none of them work. Pylint says the error is on line 8, despite what I believe to be the error on line 7. If I only have the `*` it passes the pylint checks.

Any suggestions?

```
 def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
    """prints how many days it takes for a population to reach a certain 
       number, if the population is doubling daily"""
    current_pop = initial_population
    num_days = 0
    while current_pop < final_population:
        increase = current_pop *= 2
        current_pop = current_pop + increase
        num_days += 1
    return num_days
```

Comment: In a while loop, you probably want `==` (comparison), not `=` (assignment)

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do this using python

```
increase = current_pop *= 2
```

Here is an alternative

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
    """prints how many days it takes for a population to reach a certain 
       number, if the population is doubling daily"""
    current_pop = initial_population
    num_days = 0
    while current_pop < final_population:
        current_pop *= 2
        increase = current_pop
        current_pop = current_pop + increase
        num_days += 1
    return num_days
```